# How to efficiently extract the most inner content inside this class?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to replace the value of `href` with the inner value of the class `lienarticle` in the following text

```
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925">mono</a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925"><i>aimer</i></a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925"><b>you</b></a>
```

My method of achieving my goal is rudimentary as follows

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925">mono</a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925"><i>aimer</i></a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925"><b>you</b></a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.lienarticle'):
    a['href'] = 'entry://' + str(a.contents[0]).replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', '').replace('<i>', '').replace('</i>', '')
```

The desired result is

```
<a class="lienarticle" href="entry://mono">mono</a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="entry://aimer"><i>aimer</i></a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="entry://you"><b>you</b></a>
```

I would like to ask for a more efficient way to do so, not just replacing string as mine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `.text` method

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925">mono</a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925"><i>aimer</i></a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925"><b>you</b></a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.lienarticle'):
    a['href'] = f'entry://{a.text}'
    print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
<a class="lienarticle" href="entry://mono">mono</a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="entry://aimer"><i>aimer</i></a>
<a class="lienarticle" href="entry://you"><b>you</b></a>
```